# Mapping over a dictionary in Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Say I have a dictionary in Earth Engine as follows:

```
var dictionary = ee.Dictionary({
  key1: null,
  key2: null,
  key3: null
});
```

How do I use the map() function to change all the values of each key to a string "NoData" instead of null? According to the documentation for map(), I need to write a function consisting of two arguments: a key from a dictionary and a value, though I am unsure how to write this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular example, you can do this:

```
// map over the dictionary
var mappedDictionary = dictionary.map(function(key, val){
  return 'noData';
});
```

If you have non-null data in the dictionary, you could also use the val argument, see the example in the link.

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e8e97cf7ee185cd137816f9868dfea9)